# Changing X-axis DateTime Intervals in Matplotlib to show only minutes, in order from first entry to last

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime

I have the following code (which actually mimics what I have in my real project - where the data comes from other sources):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the starting datetime
start_datetime = datetime(2024, 1, 1)

# Create a dictionary with 100 entries
sample_dictionary = {}
for i in range(100):
    # Generate the datetime key
    key = start_datetime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")[:-3]  # Remove the microseconds

    # Add the entry to the dictionary
    random_integer = random.randint(30, 500)
    sample_dictionary[key] = random_integer

    # Increment the datetime for the next entry
    random_step_seconds = random.randint(5, 120)
    start_datetime += timedelta(seconds=random_step_seconds)

# Print the sample dictionary
# Convert datetime strings to datetime objects
datetime_objects = [datetime.strptime(key, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f") for key in sample_dictionary.keys()]
integer_values = list(sample_dictionary.values())

fg, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.set_xlabel('Dictation DT')
axs.set_ylabel('TAT in minutes')
axs.set_title('TAT over the last x hours')

axs.plot(datetime_objects, integer_values, marker='o')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The display for this is:

[image]

I want to show in the X axis only the time component, hh:mm. How do I do that? And I also want to control how often to display the ticks on the X axis (hh:mm) since if the graph has many more points, I don't really need to display every corresponding X time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [matplotlib.dates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) for that. Just call [matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator) with `mdates.MinuteLocator()` and with a required `interval` value. The "hh:mm" format for the x axis can be set with [matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter) and `mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")` like this:

```py
# your code

import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# your code

# labelled ticks every 20 minutes
axs.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=20))
axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))

# your code
```

The output:

[image]